# Equivalent of case in SQL in excel

Tags: excel, case

I have a data in excel with a column(x) with only numeric values. I want to put a formula where i can get following output:

Case
When x between 1 and 4 then 10
When x between 5 and 9 then 15
.
.
.
Else x as [raised]

Answer (score 0):

The SUMPRODUCT function can be used:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((A1<=4)*10)+((A1>=5)*(A1<=9)*15)+((A1>=10)*A1))
```